# Can I return or resolve a promise in a .then in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, https, promise, return

I want the wrapping function to return the value in the .then inside of it, so I can use it later on.

I have the following code where I first have a request function that returns a promise, then I have the statusCurrent function wrapper that sits around it and calls the request function. I am able to get the value in the .then of the request, but I need to return it in the status Current function. I have tried many a solution and am stuck.

its the very end where I am consoling data which I am stuck at.

Here is my code. I am not very familiar with promises, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function request(opts) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    https
      .request(opts, function (res) {
        res.pipe(process.stdout);
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let body = "";
        res.on("data", (chunk) => (body += chunk));
        res.on("end", () => {
          //console.log("test1")
          //console.log(body);
          let json = JSON.parse(body);
          test = json.state;
          //console.log("test")
          resolve(json.state);
        });
      })
      .end(opts.body || "");
  });
}

function statusCurrent() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(
      aws4.sign(
        {
          hostname: "-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          service: "iotdata",
          region: "us-east-1",
          method: "GET",
          path: "/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json0",
          },
        },
        {
          secretAccessKey: "",
          accessKeyId: "",
        }
      )
    ).then(function (val) {
      //console.log("val")
      //console.log(val)
      // THIS CONSOLES THE VALUE CORRECTLY
      resolve(val);
    });
  });
}

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = `You're current status is`;

    statusCurrent().then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      //THIS CURRENTLY CONSOLES NOTHING
      console.log("data");
    });

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput).getResponse();
  },
};
```

Comment: I know this isn't exatcly a usefull answer, but request as been deprecated, consider using a package that handle promise natively, I recommand got: https://www.npmjs.com/package/got instead of request.

Comment: ok I will definitely consider moving, but i'd like to get my feature working first, I don't feel I am far off.

Comment: Does got have a way to work with aws4 iam authetication. Do you know of a minimal example. that was a headache to get working in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of async/await operations? They allow you write Promises more legibly

```
async function statusCurrent() {
   const awsResult = await aws4.sign(
    {
      hostname: "-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      service: "iotdata",
      region: "us-east-1",
      method: "GET",
      path: "/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json0",
      },
    },
    {
      secretAccessKey: "",
      accessKeyId: "",
    }
  )
  const requestResult = await request(awsResult)
  return requestResult
}
```

The variable awsResult contains the value that the promise of aws.sign resolves to, while requestResult contains the value that promise of request resolves to

Comment: how do I get the value in the LaunchRequestHandler function I just get a asnyc/await function returned. I tried . then there as well. Do I need to make the lantchRequest async and await in there

Comment: Also I was await of async/await but have never really understood it. I think I ahve a small grasp now. Thanks. And its working

Comment: There's no point in `await request(awsResult)`. Just `return request(awsResult)` avoids an extra promise.

Comment: Just make the LaunchRequestHandler function async and you can await promises inside it. Read up on async/await, it is less hassle to maintain than .then approach

Comment: @ggorlen They both return the same thing, so it does not matter